# How to set a global variable to specify time between http requests?

Tags: ios, swift, httprequest, nsurlsession

I'm using http request with JSON serialization in collectionViews, but the API interval is limited.

"We do enforce a small amount of rate limiting. Our current limits are 40 requests every 10 seconds and are limited by IP address, not API key. You can think of this is being burstable to 40 in a single second, or as an average of 4 requests/second. The timer will reset 10 seconds from your first request within the current 10 second "bucket". This means that if you trigger the limit you will have to wait up to 9 seconds before the timer resets but depending where you are within the 10 second window, it could be the very next second.

You can use the X-RateLimit headers that get returned with every request to keep track of your current limits. If you exceed the limit, you will receive a 429 HTTP status with a Retry-After header. As soon your cool down period expires, you are free to continue making requests."

Source: https://developers.themoviedb.org/3/getting-started/request-rate-limiting

I will like to know if it is possible to set a global variable on application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:) that will automatically increase time between all http requests that are made, I need to avoid to trigger the 10 seconds waiting timmer.

```
private func requestJSON(for dataItem: Movie) -> UIImage? {

    let query = dataItem.title!.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed)
    let requestURL = URL(string: "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=25149a6f75e14fb0672911327a13939a&language=en-US&query=\(query!)&page=1&include_adult=false&year=\(dataItem.primary_release_year!)")!

    if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: requestURL) {

        if let JSON = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as? [String: Any] {

            if let x = JSON?["results"] as? [Dictionary<String, Any>], let y = x.first {

                if let pp = y["poster_path"] as? String {

                    dataItem.poster = try? Data(contentsOf: URL(string: defaultBaseURL + pp)!)

                    print("Downloading... \(dataItem.title!)'s poster.")
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return dataItem.poster?.first != nil ? UIImage(data: dataItem.poster!) : UIImage(named: "default-movie")
}
```

I will like to avoid to use lots of tasks as much as I can where possible, anyway, any other solution will also be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no global variable, `NSURLSessionConfiguration` property or anything built into iOS that implements this - you'll have to do this yourself.

Comment: Any idea for an approach?

Comment: Too much depends on what your app does to really answer. I'd probably start by ignoring the limit and measuring of how often you hit it in normal usage.